# Validate form using react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to implement form validation using `react-hook-form` I tried this:

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    // This generic will type the data response correctly.
    // So the errors object and register function will infer the types of TicketDTO.
  } = useForm<TicketDTO>({
    defaultValues: {
      title: "",
      description: "",
    },
  });

const onSubmit = async (data: TicketDTO) => {
    console.log(data);

    // This console.log won't give errors
    // console.log(data.title);
    // This console.log will give typing errors
    // console.log(data.randomValue);
    updateTicket(data)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data.title);
        history.replace("/support");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Load for data using this code:

```
const [ticket, setTicket] = useState<TicketDTO>();

  useEffect(() => {
    ticketCategoriesData();
    getSingleTicket();
  }, []);

const getSingleTicket = async () => {
    getTicket(requestParams.id)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setTicket(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

Form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={classes.form}>
<TextField
                        value={ticket?.title}
                        id="title"
                        label="Issue Name *"
                        style={{ margin: 8 }}
                        {...register("title", {
                          required: true,
                          maxLength: 40,
                        })}
                        placeholder="Issue Name"
                        helperText="Enter Issue name"
                        fullWidth
                        margin="normal"
                        InputLabelProps={{
                          shrink: true,
                        }}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                          setTicket({ ...ticket, title: value });
                        }}
                        // error={true}
                      />
</form>
```

Service:

```
export async function getTicket(
    id: string
) {
  return await axios.get(
      `${baseUrl}/management/support/tickets/ticket/${id}`
  );
}

export async function updateTicket(
    data: TicketDTO
): Promise<AxiosResponse<TicketDTO>> {
  return await axios.post<TicketDTO>(`${baseUrl}/support/tickets/ticket/${data.id}`, {
    data,
  });
}

export interface TicketDTO {
    id?: number,
    title?: string,
    description?: string,
}
```

But when I try to make a update I get POST error: `/api/support/tickets/ticket/undefined`

Looks like the `id` value is not properly send. Do you know how I can fix this issue? If I change `id?: number,` to `id: number,` I get error `TS2345: Argument of type '{ title: string; id?: number | undefined; description?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<TicketDTO | undefined>'.`

Comment: Does it show the data correctly in here `const onSubmit = async (data: TicketDTO) => {
    console.log(data);  ...}`

Comment: Yes, I get `{title: '463acd82b40', description: 'tyjtyjty'}
description: "tyjtyjty"
title: "463acd82b40"
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: I does not have `id` whereas you are trying to use id here `axios.post<TicketDTO>(${baseUrl}/support/tickets/ticket/${data.id}`. data should have id

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: I agree. How I can keep the id hidden?

Comment: You must provide an id or use another value for dynamic request: `${data.id}` > `${data.title}

Comment: Ok, the only thing left is this: `setTicket({ ...ticket, title: value });` I get `TS2345: Argument of type '{ title: string; id?: number | undefined; description?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<TicketDTO | undefined>'.   Type '{ title: string; id?: number | undefined; description?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'TicketDTO'.     Types of property 'id' are incompatible.       Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable `

Comment: I don't understand typescript type stuff well. I use vanillajs. So, sorry I could not understand